# Запятая перед "такой же"

Tags: пунктуация

"Он сделался просто Кони, такой же гражданин, как и все". Нужна ли запятая перед такой? Почему?

Comment: Смысл не вполне ясен. Сделался *таким же гражданином*?

Comment: Да. "И тотчас же в обглоданном войной Петрограде он сделался просто Кони, такой же гражданин, как и все".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Нужна, потому что приложение стоит после определяемого слова - имени собственного.